# Interactive 3d model using flutter

Tags: flutter, animation, model, 3d, game-development

I want to make a flutter app that loads a 3d modal and when the user clicks on a 3D model's particular part and then goes to another 3d modal how does that.

Like the app loads a 3d model of a street it contains 4 shops when the user clicks on shop-1 then I won't show that shop 3d model but if any user clicks on shop-2 then do nothing.

How do this in Flutter?